# how do I call a class variable by its value

Tags: python-2.7

Ok so I have the class variable "name", which is random by a list of names,

```
class Man(object):
  def __init__(self, name, age)
      self.name = "dylan"
      self.age = 4
```

Now I want to call age, by "dylan"

So I want to do "dylan".age, basically.

How can I do this? Call a variable of a class by its Value?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks to me like "name" is an instance variable not a class variable. If that's so, there's no way to access it unless you already have a reference to the instance "dylan".

Could you make a dictionary to store references to all the instances you create?
`men["dylan"] = Man("dylan", 42)`?

Then you can write `men["dylan"].age` with any luck!

Answer (score 1):

This will only work if each name is unique.

First create two accessor methods in your object class that return age and name.

```
def get_name(self):
    return self.name

def get_age(self):
    return self.age
```

Then, create a method using a for loop that iterates through each object in your list. Call for the object name, compare it to the name you're looking for, and if it matches return the age.

```
def find_age_of(sought_name):
    for obj in obj_list:
        if (obj.get_name().lower() == sought_name.lower()):    #'.lower' negates case differences
            return sought_age = obj.get_age()
```

Finally, call this method using the name as a parameter:

```
sought_name = 'dylan'
sought_age = find_age_of(sought_name)
```

Comment: thank you, that was very well written, however I think creating a dictionary as Steve Pitchers suggested might be a better idea for my purposes. :)

Answer (score -1):

Make a getter that returns the age

```
getAge
{
    return self.age;
}
```

Comment: I want to call it outside the class, f.ex if i have.        man1 = Man("dylan", 2)     and i want to call "2" by typing "dylan"